# Show any graph G contains an r-partite subgraph H with e(H) $\geq \frac{r-1}{r} e(G)$

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to show that for any $r \geq 2$, any graph G contains an r-partite subgraph H with e(H) $\geq \frac{r-1}{r} e(G)$

I'm supposed to be using the first moment method in probabilistic combinatorics, ie. finding some events, working out their probability and bounding them to show the above occurs wp 1, but I don't know where to start/what events to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is more elementary method then you are thinking about. First of all let's prove that there is $r$-partite subgraph $H$ such that. 
$$
d_H(v) \ge \frac{r-1}{r} d_G(v), v \in V(G).
$$
Let's partition our vertices into $r$ subsets such that the induced bipartite graph has maximum number of edges. Let's take some vertex $v$. Now we claim that it has not more than $\frac{1}{r}d_G(v)$ neighbors in it's partition, otherwise there is a set in which $v$ has not more than $\frac{1}{r}d_G(v)$ neighbors, so we can put $v$ in that set and increase number of edges. Now we have 
$$
e(H) = \frac{1}{2}\sum d_H(v)\ge\frac{1}{2}\frac{r-1}{r}\sum d_G(v)=\frac{r-1}{r}e(G).
$$

Comment: could you clarify how you prove the first result- how are we able to repeat the process of finding a subset in which v has no more than $ \frac{1}{r} d\_{G} (v)$ neighbours? How exactly are we picking which vertices/edges go into H?

Comment: I am sorry the initial proof was not correct. We should consider not any random partition, but one which has maximum number of edges. Is it clear now?

Comment: do you mean the induced r-partite graph? and then when you say 'otherwise there is a set in which v has not more than $ \frac{1}{r} d_{G}(v)$ neighbours', why is that true?

Comment: Yes I mean the induced r-partite graph. Because it would have more than $r*\frac{1}{r}d_G(v)=d_G(v)$ neighbors, which is obviously a contradiction.

Comment: oh yeah, woops, that's very obvious! thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome!